# How do I filter rows out of a CSV file based on two or more boolean conditions?

Tags: dataframe

So I am trying to filter out rows based on two boolean conditions.

'When I ran the code below, which filters out rows based on the one condition that the value in the column is equal to two, and it worked. '

'''
is_2 = dataframe['column']==2
'''

'However, when I tried to filter out rows where the value in the column is equal to 2 or 3, I ran the code below and it gave me an error.'

'''
is_2_or_3 = dataframe[column]==2 |dataframe[column]==3
'''

Answer (score 0):

It's because `|` is prior than the `==`, you need use parentheses to ensure the operator precedence.

```py
(dataframe[column]==2) | (dataframe[column]==3)
```